# Refresh data on JLabel - Java SWING

Tags: java, swing, jframe, refresh, jlabel

I'm trying to Refresh my data on JLabel Text.
My data on "mod.getAllPlaneteByUser(u).getQte_or()" get data from my DataBase.

The component "lblRefresh" is just a JLabel listener.

--> Initialization :

```
JLabel lblRessOr = new JLabel();
lblRessOr.setText(Integer.toString(mod.getAllPlaneteByUser(u).getQte_or()));
```

--> Add By default on my contentPane :

```
lblRessOr.setForeground(Color.RED);
lblRessOr.setFont(new Font("Lucida Grande", Font.BOLD, 16));
lblRessOr.setBounds(225, 141, 73, 16);
contentPane.add(lblRessOr);
```

--> Use on my MouseListener :

```
if(e.getSource() == lblRefresh){
     lblRefresh.setText(Integer.toString(mod.getAllPlaneteByUser(u).getQte_or()));
     lblRefresh.repaint();
}
```

Anybody know how i can refresh my data ?

Comment: It seems like you need to repaint the entire frame and not just the label.

Comment: I tried to repaint the entire frame but no result.

Comment: Do you want to refresh the data as soon as someone writes anything within the label ??

Comment: I get data from MySql  and i would like refresh with a button my JLabel but i old result of my query Select. I would like to get new data.

Answer (score 0):

If you are attempting to change the text in the lblRessOr Jlabel you would place the below code in your listener block.

```
if(e.getSource().equals(lblRefresh)){
    lblRessOr.setText(Integer.toString(mod.getAllPlaneteByUser(u).getQte_or()));
}
```

Comment: Yes i do this and no result, the text put on my "lblRessOr" is not appear on my JFrame.